# Python Flask: How to save the data from page

Tags: python, flask

Is anyone wrapping up flask in python well? I have a registration form but I don't know how to save the data from that page, like name and password, so I can read it later.

Save to a separate file of type:

```
file = open(file.txt)
file.write(username + password)
```

does not work when I already host the page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, can you provide your code? What would you like to create? Is it a simple web application that requires registration and authorization or is it just a form from which you would like to take some data?

Secondly, there is some good tutorials in the Internet about [Flask registration.](https://medium.com/codex/simple-registration-login-system-with-flask-mongodb-and-bootstrap-8872b16ef915) Moreover, you can read [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-collect-input-from-an-HTML-form-and-store-it-in-a-file-which-in-turn-could-be-accessed-by-a-Python-program). [Here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/) there is a Flask student book. You can search for something different if this tutorial will not actual and proper for you.

Thirdly, about saving data in the textual file .txt from flask app. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643970/insert-or-write-data-to-txt-file-with-flask).

**UPD.** For the last variant with file.

*app.py*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request 

app = Flask(__name__) 
     
@app.route('/') 
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html') 
     
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST']) 
def get_data(): 
    login = request.form['login']
    password = request.form['password']
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        with open('data.txt', 'a+') as f:
            f.write(str(login) + ' ' + str(password) + '\n')
    return render_template("index.html") 
     
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(debug = True)
```

*templates/index.html*

```
<html> 
   <body> 
    
     <form action="" method="POST"> 
         <p>Login <input name="login" /></p> 
         <p>Password <input name="password" /></p> 
         <p><input type="submit"></p> 
      </form> 
       
   </body> 
</html>
```